# selected options sum using JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some selectors, and they all have some options with some values. How do I sum all values of selected options and also attach the sum to a input field?

```
<select name='sel1'>
 <option value='40'>40 </option>
 <option value='50'>50 </option>
</select>

<select name='sel2'>
 <option value='10'>10 </option>
 <option value='20'>20 </option>
</select>
```

I have tried this:

```
$('select').change(function(){
  var sum = 0;
  $('selected').each(function() {
    sum += Number($(this).val());
  });
  $("#roomnumber").val(sum);
});
```

Comment: And what have you tried yourself?

Comment: Use `.each()` to get the value of each select, `parseInt()` to convert it to a number, then add it to the sum variable. All very simple operations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this

```
$("select[name^='sel']").change(function() {
  var s = $('select[name^="sel"] option:selected').map(function() {
    return this.value
  }).get()

  var sum = s.reduce((pv, cv) => {
    return pv + (parseFloat(cv) || 0);
  }, 0);

  $("#sum").val(sum)
})
```

```js
$("select[name^='sel']").change(function() {
  var s = $('select[name^="sel"] option:selected').map(function() {
    return this.value
  }).get()

  var sum = s.reduce((pv, cv) => {
    return pv + (parseFloat(cv) || 0);
  }, 0);

  $("#sum").val(sum)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name='sel1'>
 <option value='40'>40 </option>
 <option value='50'>50 </option>
</select>

<select name='sel2'>
 <option value='10'>10 </option>
 <option value='20'>20 </option>
 </select>

<input id="sum" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Give same name to each of your select tag (eg. name="s").

```
var arr = document.getElementsByName('s');
var sum = 0;
for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
    sum+=parseInt(arr[i].value);
}
console.log(sum);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is almost correct, the issue is simply that `selected` is not a valid selector. To retrieve the selected `option` elements use `option:selected` instead:

```js
$('select').change(function() {
  var sum = 0;
  $('option:selected').each(function() {
    sum += parseInt($(this).val(), 10);
  });
  $("#roomnumber").val(sum);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name='sel1'>
 <option value='40'>40 </option>
 <option value='50'>50 </option>
</select>

<select name='sel2'>
 <option value='10'>10 </option>
 <option value='20'>20 </option>
</select>

<input id="roomnumber" type="text" />
```

Answer (score 0):

here is JSfiddle link : https://jsfiddle.net/fesi39/apb8as1h/

```js
$('select').change(function(){
var sum = 0; 
$('.selecter').find(":selected").each(function(){
  sum = sum +  parseInt($(this).val());
    $('span').html(sum);
});
});
```

```html
<div class='selecter'>
<select name='sel1'>
 <option value='40'>40 </option>
 <option value='50'>50 </option>
</select>

<select name='sel2'>
 <option value='10'>10 </option>
 <option value='20'>20 </option>
</select>
<h2>result <span class='resultAppend'></span></h2>
</div>  

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```